# How is AngularJS able to discern between these two properties?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I understand that `ng-model` will create a property that then relates to the `{{name}}`.

How does AngularJS discern between the `{{name}}` that comes from the `ng-model` and the `{{name}}` that comes from the `ng-repeat`/`ng-init`?

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="container" data-ng-init="names=['Conner', 'Bryan', 'Cathy', 'Jim']">
        <div class="row">
           <em>Input your name: </em> <input type="text" data-ng-model="name">
           <h4>{{name}}</h4>
           <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="name in names"> {{name}} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Moreover, can I choose any placeholder text for the `ng-repeat` name?

Comment: They're in different contexts. Outside of the ng-repeat, `name` refers to the one created by `data-ng-model="name"`. Inside the ng-repeat `name` refers to each name within the names array, very similar to what happens when you use `[].forEach()`. and, yes, you could replace `name in names` with `whatever in names`.

Comment: It doesn't do any sort and yes you can use anything as variable name for `name`

Comment: So this is a matter of variable scope then? @KevinB

Comment: well, i'm not versed in the angular source code so i can't say for sure how it gets compiled and ran, but the result matches the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Child scope overrides parent scope on name collisions.  Check out *Scope Hierarchies* in the [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) which says:

> When Angular evaluates `{{name}}`, it first looks at the scope
>   associated with the given element for the `name` property. If no such
>   property is found, it searches the parent scope and so on until the
>   root scope is reached.

You can, and probably should for clarity, use a different variable name in the repeater;

```
<li data-ng-repeat="firstName in names"> {{firstName}} </li>
```